# Программа прекращает работу после первого значения <Y>

Tags: c

Программа прекращает работу после первого значения , игнорируя условия цикла.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    double begin = 0, step = 0, end = 0, count = 0, y = 0, x = 0;

    printf("Введи начальное значение отрезка: ");
    scanf("%f", &begin);
    printf("Введи шаг перехода по отрезку: ");
    scanf("%f", &step);
    printf("Введи конечное значение отрезка: ");
    scanf("%f", &end);

    for (count = begin; count < end; count = count + step)
    {
        if (count < 0)
        {
            y = (pow (abs(count), count));
        }
        else if (0 <= count <= 1)
        {
            y = (1/(tan(2*count)+1));
        }
        else
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                count = count - count*2;
                y = (pow (count, count), pow (M_E, count));
            }
            else
                y = (pow (count, count), pow (M_E, count));
        }
        printf("Значение функции <y> %f ", y, '\n');
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Тестовые условия:**

1. Введи начальное значение отрезка: 3
2. Введи шаг перехода по отрезку: 1
3. Введи конечное значение отрезка: 5

Программа выполняет один расчёт и прекращает работу цикла

Comment: покажите тестовые значение что вы вводите

Comment: Введи начальное значение отрезка: 3
Введи шаг перехода по отрезку: 1
Введи конечное значение отрезка: 5

Comment: лучше добавить это на сам вопрос. нажмите "править" и отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

у вас во втором обороте срабатывает код

```
count = count - count*2;
y = (pow (count, count), pow (M_E, count));
```

тут у `y` нет правильной значении, тут `y=((-2^(-2)) , (M_E^(-2))` как видите, y должен бить `double`. а правая сторона не `double`

**UPD**

вроде должно быть

```
y = (pow (count, count) * pow (M_E, count));
```

Comment: Так?
y = (pow (count, count) * (double)(pow (M_E, count)))

Comment: у вас в коде не так

Comment: Дело не только в этом когда я поставил везде 7*7, программа все равно выполняется один раз.

Comment: Всё я её уже сделал, но пришлось все переменные в int отнести, а У - сделать float

Comment: ` y = (pow (count, count), pow (M_E, count));` на что поменяли?

Comment: переделал на y = ((powf (count, count)) * (powf (M_E, count)));
int begin = 0, step = 0, end = 0, count = 0, x = 0; float y = 0;

Comment: @nicolia ну вот, вы же поменяли на `*` а у вас было `,`.

Comment: То есть это верный шаг?

Comment: @nicolia ну.. да. Так как если там стоит `,` это точно ошибка. а `*` это уже один из правельных. Вы правильно сделали :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wyRvfejS вроде бы всё:)

Comment: @nicolia да теперь правильно